# How to always select the highest available quality on youtube video with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='button.ytp-button.ytp-settings-button').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="/html/body/ytd-app/div[1]/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/ytd-player/div/div/div[30]/div/div/div[3]").click()
```

Some videos have their highest quality 1080p, others have 1440p and others have 4k and so on, how do I make selenium click the on that is the highest.

I was thinking of doing something like to append all the qualites available to a list and then just go with the list[0] or list[-1]. Depends what index does the highest available quality takes.

[image: Example1]

[image: Example2]

Comment: I mean I can use this `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//span[contains(string(),'1080p')]").click()` but it is only for the 1080p option. Maybe if I put them in an if statement I could work around with that. But is there a more fast way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to set the maximum available resolution (or the top one), you don't need to rely on strings defining the resolutions. Just click the first button that exists. Also, the answer you posted isn't a good practice (use loops instead)

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value='(//div[@class="ytp-menuitem"])[1]').click()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//span[contains(string(),'2160p')]").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//span[contains(string(),'1440p')]").click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        try:
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//span[contains(string(),'1080p')]").click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            try:
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//span[contains(string(),'720p')]").click()
            except NoSuchElementException:
                try:
                    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//span[contains(string(),'480p')]").click()
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    try:
                        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//span[contains(string(),'360p')]").click()
                    except NoSuchElementException:
                        try:
                            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//span[contains(string(),'240p')]").click()
                        except NoSuchElementException:
                            try:
                                driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//span[contains(string(),'144p')]").click()
                            except NoSuchElementException:
                                print("App has crashed")  # Do not think code can reach here, but just in case
                                exit()
```

Did this should be good, if there is something "faster" would be appreciated.